# TYPO3 EXT:powermail prefill or preselect a field via url

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I have my own TYPO3 plugin that displays records. Now I want to add a link to a second page to each record.

The second page should be a powermail form. Now I want that the link to the second Mail contains a parameter that should prefill a input field in the powermail form.

Is that possible? And if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See documentation of powermail: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/PrefillField/Index.html

**The standard way**

Prefilling (input, textarea, hidden) or preselecting (select, check, radio) of fields will be done by the PrefillFieldViewHelper. It listen to the following methods and parameters (in this ordering):

1. GET/POST param like &tx_powermail_pi1[field][marker]=value
2. GET/POST param like &tx_powermail_pi1[marker]=value
3. GET/POST param like &tx_powermail_pi1[field][123]=value
4. GET/POST param like &tx_powermail_pi1[uid123]=value
5. If field should be filled with values from FE_User (see field configuration)
6. If field should be prefilled from static Setting (see field configuration)
7. Fill with TypoScript cObject like

   ```
   plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill {
       # Fill field with marker {email}
       email = TEXT
       email.value = mail@domain.org
   }
   ```
8. Fill with simple TypoScript like

   ```
   plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill {
       # Fill field with marker {email}
       email = mail@domain.org
   }
   ```
9. Fill with your own PHP with a Signal. Look at In2codePowermailViewHelpersMiscPrefillFieldViewHelper::render()